# Problems Compiling build.xml in Android SDK with Processing

Tags: java, android, ant, compilation, processing

I'm running the newest version of Processing(v2.1) and the newest version of the Android SDK. I installed the SDK according to the tutorial on the Processing website, but that tutorial is very outdated, and so are any other tutorials I find on the topic. When I run any Android application in Processing Android mode, I get this compiler error:

```
-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
Installed at /Users/anonymous/Desktop/Programming/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: FirstAndroid
Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for FirstAndroid...
Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
API level:        10
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for FirstAndroid...
Library dependencies:
No Libraries

------------------
API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /var/folders/hw/4lr3l8jx2qs7rkk_m29qmm343hkg0f/T/android4330892161628182717sketch/bin/classes
    [javac] Unable to locate an executable at "/Users/anonymous/Desktop/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/javac" (-1)
    [javac] Unable to locate an executable at "/Users/anonymous/Desktop/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/javac" (-1)

BUILD FAILED
/Users/anonymous/Desktop/Programming/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/anonymous/Desktop/Programming/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Any advice on how to get it running would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the latest Java installed on your system and uninstall the current ADT you have.

Get the latest Android Developer Tool here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to downgrade to Processing 2.01. My Android sketch is working now. Be sure you are using API 10 in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:
1 update new version of java javac from 1.6 to 1.7 ,  fail .
2 added all versions of android API to newest  . fail
3 remove some version android API (leaving android-17 android-19 ) . work finally.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, I don't know what exactly causes the issue, but according to the error output, it seems that processing is trying to use the javac which is supposed to be in the application's package while it's not. So what I did is just to replace processing's built-in java distribution with my own , and it worked. 
Here is what I did:

```
cd /Applications/Processing.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents
mv Home Home.backup
ln -s $JAVA_HOME Home
```

Well, I just used $JAVA_HOME since I have exported it, you can also replace it with your JDK's path.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the OpenJDK-Devel package gets you past this error.

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```